# Filter rows in numpy array based on second array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 2d numpy arrays A and B
I want to remove all the rows in A which appear in B.

I tried something like this:

```
A[~np.isin(A, B)]
```

but isin keeps the dimensions of A, I need one boolean value per row to filter it.

EDIT: something like this

```
A = np.array([[3, 0, 4],
              [3, 1, 1],
              [0, 5, 9]])
B = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
              [3, 1, 1]])

.....

A = np.array([[3, 0, 4],
              [0, 5, 9]])
```

Comment: I think a short example would better illustrate your question

Comment: How big are your arrays in practice? Are the items bounded to a small value? Are they always positives integers?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most performant solution, but does exactly what you want. You can change the dtype of `A` and `B` to be a unit consisting of one row. You need to ensure that the arrays are contiguous first, e.g. with [`ascontiguousarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html):

```
Av = np.ascontiguousarray(A).view(np.dtype([('', A.dtype, A.shape[1])])).ravel()
Bv = np.ascontiguousarray(B).view(Av.dtype).ravel()
```

Now you can apply [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) directly:

```
>>> np.isin(Av, Bv)
array([False,  True, False])
```

According to the docs, `invert=True` is faster than negating the output of `isin`, so you can do

```
A[np.isin(Av, Bv, invert=True)]
```

Comment: This is clever, but: `A = np.array([[3, 0, 4], [3, 1, 1], [0, 5, 9]], order="F")` (and before you go "oh that's just a weird corner condition", that's the order returned by `.transpose()`)

Comment: @CJR. I am quite aware of where `order='F'` comes in. Clearly this only works if the last axis is contiguous. Being able to create a view with Fortran ordered arrays is actually deprecated and you should see a warning. I removed it for the next release: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20722

Comment: What about using a copy to ensure the ordering/contiguity is correct?

Comment: Well that's good - it'll be easier to catch an exception than to keep checking array properties before using a view. Here I'd suggest `np.array(A, order="C").view(...)`. I do also like that this works on any dtype instead of being limited to integers.

Comment: @JérômeRichard. That's a good idea. [`np.ascontiguousarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html) seems to me made for the job.

Comment: @JérômeRichard. Added

Comment: @CJR. Fixed the copy issue

Answer (score 1):

Try the following - it uses matrix multiplication for dimensionality reduction:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[3, 0, 4],
              [3, 1, 1],
              [0, 5, 9]])
B = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
              [3, 1, 1]])

arr_max = np.maximum(A.max(0) + 1, B.max(0) + 1)
print (A[~np.isin(A.dot(arr_max), B.dot(arr_max))])
```

Output:

```
[[3 0 4]
 [0 5 9]]
```

Comment: Oh wow, yes this does what I wanted, removing rows from A which are present in B.
But I have no idea how it works :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is clever, but: `A = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]])` and `B = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]])`

Comment: Clever. Not perfect, but a great idea

Comment: The answer probably does *not* always works since the dot product does not generate *unique* values. I think a cumulated product is missing (like when we flatten an ND array). Additionally, if the maximum value is big or the size of the array is big, then there will certainly be some *overflows* causing bugs.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, this type of reindexing would work with `np.cumsum(np.insert(np.maximum(A.max(0) + 1, B.max(0) + 1), 0, 0))[:-1]`. It also only works for integer arrays, as a caveat.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the most performant solution but it is relatively easy to read:

```
A = np.array([row for row in A if row not in B])
```

**Edit:**

I found that the code does not correctly work, but this does:

```
A = [row for row in A if not any(np.equal(B, row).all(1))]
```